# Yes/No : Is $g$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement true/false ?

> let $f$ and $g$  be two functions from $[a,b]$  to $[a,b]$  with $f$ strictly increasing .
>
> If $f$ and $f \circ g$ are  continuous , then $g$ is continuous .

My attempt : I know the following theorem : If $f$ and $f \circ g$ are  continuous, then $f^{-1}$ will exist, I mean  $f$ will be  bijective  but this theorem will contradict here:

take $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } \ x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [a,b] \\ 0 \text{ if} \ x \in \mathbb{Q^c}\cap [a,b] \end{cases}$

Now $f \circ g= f(1)= e  $ which is constant function but $g$ is  not continuous

So the given above statement is false

Is it true ?

Comment: $f\circ g(x) = \begin{cases}e^{1}& x\in \mathbb{Q}\\ e^{0}& x \notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$ so it isnt continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f\circ g(x) = \begin{cases}e^{1}& x\in \mathbb{Q}\\ e^{0}& x \notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$ so it isn't continuous. Now if $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing then $f^{-1}:[f(0),f(1)]\rightarrow [0,1]$ does not only exist, it is also continuous. How do you proceed from here?

Comment: yes @Olof  thanks u    but im thinking such that  function that will contradicts my given statement

Comment: But it doesn't contradict your statement since $f\circ g$ is not continuous in your case.

Comment: In the setting described by the poster Jasmine, namely the one in which $f: [a, b] \to [a, b]$ is continuous and strictly monotonous, one cannot in general claim anything about $f$ being invertible, because it is not in general surjective. An easy example of such an instance is $[0, 1] \to [0, 1], x \mapsto x/2$. It will of course be the case that $_{\mathrm{Im}f\ |}f$, the corestriction of $f$ to its range is a homeomorphism, but no more can be said beyond that, in general.

Comment: Ah yes this is correct I was sloppy. I will update my answer so that it is correct

Comment: @Olof: Your edited update has not gone unnoticed, but may I say (with a somewhat pedantic and exigent tone) that matters are still not yet impeccable: for a function $f$ the syntax $f^{-1}$ is not licit unless it really truly were an invertible function; if it is only injective (but not necessarily surjective) its corestriction to its range will indeed be a bijection but then the inverse of this corestriction must be written accordingly, not as though it were the inverse of $f$ itself (which in general it is not).